# How can I properly fix the vertical alignment of the tombstone (QED sign) in list-proofs?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsthm

I frequently encounter the following situation: I am proving a claim which consists of multiple sub-claims, which I've enumerated in a list using the `enumerate` environment provided by the eponymous package. The proof then also takes the form of such a list. At the end of the proof, the tombstone (a.k.a. QED symbol) appears vertically offset from the final line of the last item of this list. Here's a minimal working example to see this behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document} 

\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Problem
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document
```

I don't like this behavior, and would like the tombstone to appear vertically aligned with the final line of the last item. So far, I've gotten by with some quick and dirty solutions (using negative `\vspace`) but I've now come across a case where that doesn't work (because of page breaking). So I'm looking for a *proper* solution.

I've taken a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282762/qed-vertical-alignment-in-beamer), which the site's algorithm suggested to me while typing this up, but didn't like the quick and dirty way suggested there (and wasn't able to implement egreg's answer in a satisfactory manner).

Comment: Add `\qedhere` at the end of the last item.

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386309

Comment: @egreg I wasn't aware of this; you might want to consider turning this into an answer.

Comment: @Danu I think it's a duplicate. I don't recommend using `ntheorem`.

Comment: @egreg That is even better. In my case, it turned out that using ntheorem also caused new problems, so I've ended up using your solution (although the answer by Bernard does answer my question as posed). Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem if you load `ntheorem` with options `[amsthm,thmmarks]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsthm]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Problem A.
\item Problem B.
\item Problem C.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]