# QED-Symbol at end of cases

Tags: environments, qed

I have an environment >>Satz<< (German for >>theorem<<), which ends with a \diamond.
But if the theorem ends with cases, the diamond is not set correctly. It is either in a new line (but at least at the right edge), or it is right behind the last character in the cases (but at least in the correct line).

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cases}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}
\AtBeginEnvironment{satz}{%
  \pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\diamond$}%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{satz}{\popQED\endsatz}

\begin{document}

\begin{satz}
This works.
\end{satz}

\begin{satz}
This works.
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \bigl( g(x) \bigr) \\
h(x) &= \bigl( r(x) \bigr).\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{satz}

\begin{satz}
This
\[
\begin{cases}
    \text{does} \\ 
    \text{not}.
\end{cases}
\]
\end{satz}

\begin{satz}
And this
\[
\begin{cases}
    \text{doesn't} \\ 
    \text{either}. \qedhere
\end{cases}
\]
\end{satz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't. Add some words to finish the proof. But you can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282772/4427

Comment: @egreg Will be hard to find further words here. But I checked the link you gave me. Thank you dear Sir! Again ;)

Comment: In the last example, if `\qedhere` is placed instead after `\end{cases}, the symbol will be placed flush right on the baseline of the equation.  Still not exactly what's wanted here, but shows that placing it *inside* `cases` isn't the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

I agree in general with [what egreg says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686727/qed-symbol-at-end-of-cases#comment1704013_686727), but if you must, you can get this effect using [`empheq`](https://ctan.org/pkg/empheq?lang=en), by putting a brace to the left of an `align*`.  (I also removed the `\usepackage{cases}` since pretty much anything you want to do with that package, you can also do with `empheq`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}
\AtBeginEnvironment{satz}{%
  \pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\diamond$}%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{satz}{\popQED\endsatz}

\begin{document}
\begin{satz}
This
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
    & \text{does,} \\ 
    & \text{YAY}. \qedhere
\end{empheq}
\end{satz}

\end{document}
```