Including QED symbol in examples
I want to define my example environment to always include a \qed symbol. Can I use \newtheoremstyle{example} to do this?

You can use the proof environment of amsthm or see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/686727/277964 for the definition of a similar environment (also using amsthm + \newtheorem).

This may be helpful: How to make all theorem-like environments have an ending symbol?

It would help, if you show the example environment, you already have. Without this, I can only guess …
Assumed you are using amsthm for the example environment, you just can add the QED symbol handling to the beginning and ending of the environment using generic environment hooks:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\AddToHook{env/example/begin}{\pushQED{\qed}}
\AddToHook{env/example/end}{\popQED}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \blindtext
\end{example}

\end{document}


This should work with every theorem style defined using amsthm.
If you don't need a number, you can also use the predefined proof environment:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}[Example]
  \blindtext
\end{proof}

\end{document}


The advantage of using the \pushQED/\popQED mechanism, which is also used by proof, is that you can manipulate the position of the qed symbol using \qedhere. Here an example to show, that this can be useful:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\AddToHook{env/example/begin}{\pushQED{\qed}}
\AddToHook{env/example/end}{\popQED}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\begin{example}
  Numbered list with qed symbol after the list:
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Last item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{example}
\blindtext
\begin{example}
  Numbered list with qed symbol at the end of the last list item:
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Last item \qedhere
  \end{enumerate}
\end{example}
\blindtext

\end{document}



This fixed it! Is there a quick way to also remove the period after the number?

@curry This would be another question, e.g., this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338209/remove-dot-after-theorem-with-amsthm-and-hyperref

You can use as \newenvironment{example}{\bgroup\medskip}{\hfill\qed\medskip\egroup} (assumed that you already used amsthm package), please always post MWE from \documentclass to \end{document}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{example}{\bgroup\medskip\noindent\textbf{Example:\enskip}}{\hfill\qed\medskip\endgraf\egroup}  

\lipsum[1]

\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}



\bgroup and \egroup aren't really doing anything useful. And you have a further spurious space after \enskip. And try your code without leaving the empty line after \end{example}.

Yes, just for safety purpose, have added \bgroup and \egroup, thanks for pointing this

Mentioned error was fixed, thanks a lot
