# QED-Symbol in last line of a cases-environment

Tags: cases, qed

I know there are several topics about this, but for any reason, no one answered my exact problem.
So, I end a proof with a cases-environment and I want to set the QED-Square at the end of the last line. But it is either

1. set right after the last symbol (but in the correct line)
   or
2. in a new line (but at the correct position).

Here is my MWE which results in case 1. If I type

```
 \qedhere
```

before the  \end{cases} command, it results in case 2.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

There is

\begin{proof}
    this proof for
    \[
    \begin{cases}
        a \\
        b. 
    \end{cases}
    \]
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: related: [qed when `cases` is the last element of the proof-ending display with svmono class without amsthm and ntheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430806/123129)

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx,  You're using `amsthm`, which cooperates with `amsmath` in placing the QED symbol.  But you haven't loaded `amsmath`.  If you do that, it should place the QED at the right margin of the *baseline* of the equation containing the `cases`, but there are known ways to adjust that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I would do this, but I guess you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

There is

\begin{proof}
    this proof for
    \[
    \begin{cases}
        a &xxx\\
        b.&yyy
    \end{cases}
    \]

\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}
\mbox{}\qedhere
    \end{proof}

\noindent X\dotfill X % just for testing
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to! Thank you, dear Sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly change the code at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282772/4427

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
this proof for
\[
\begin{gathered}[b]
\begin{cases}
  a \\
  b.
\end{cases}\\[-1.2\normalbaselineskip]\mathstrut
\end{gathered}\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note. `twocolumn` is used just to make a smaller picture that better shows the alignment.

Anyway, the simplest way is to avoid such situations and finish the proof with some explicatory words.